# Errors occurred during the release build in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: android, eclipse, unsigned, signed, release-builds

Errors occurred during the release build in Eclipse IDE?

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'VuforiaSamples'.

*Launch configuration* type id "**org.eclipse.ant.AntBuilderLaunchConfigurationType**" does not exist.

Possible causes:
*Missing specification of a launch type* (missing plug-in)
Incorrect launch configuration XML

Launch configuration type id "**org.eclipse.ant.AntBuilderLaunchConfigurationType**" does not exist.

Possible causes:
Missing specification of a launch type (missing plug-in)
Incorrect launch configuration XML

Eclipse is out dated for Android Development.... Still help to few people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best solution for the problem.

1.Eclipse -> Help Menu

2.Select Install New Software.

3.Enter "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno"

4.Select "General Purpose Tools" -> "Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment"

5.Then click Next, accept license, Finish, etc, until it's installed.

6.When it's finished installing, it will prompt you to restart Eclipse. select restart eclipse.